# Populating a listbox by comparing another listbox value

Tags: ms-access, vba

How to populate a listbox with a selected row from anohter list box . I used following code for criteria to compare two listboxes. But i am not yet successful.

```
  forms![HHRRR]![List0].[ListIndex](0)
```

any help please.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Queries/Tables for your list boxes or do you have them configured to use Value Lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time I've ever done this, I've used a RowSource for the listbox, and in the OnChange event of the first listbox I constructed a SQL string and updated the RowSource of the 2nd listbox.  Something like:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = " & forms![HHRRR]![List0].Text & ""
Me.Listbox2.RowSource = sSQL
Me.Listbox2.Requery
```

This is completely "aircode" and might need a little tweaking, but you get the idea.

Comment: sir, you are write except that there is not TEXT as a list property and also need ';' to terminate the query